# ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2 while predicting digit with KNN

Tags: python, knn

The error is coming while executing the line - 
`prediction = neigh.predict(digit.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1))`  
digit.reshape is functioning properly. So the problem is with neigh.predict() 
which is the model built using KNN

The following shows the output of these statements:

```
    print(digit.ndim)
    print(digit.shape)
    print(digit.size)
2
(28, 28)
784
```

[image]

I am not sure how to fix this. What I am trying to do is load a .png file in python 
containing a handwritten digit I am then using openCV to do contouring as mentioned here 
https://yash-kukreja-98.medium.com/recognizing-handwritten-digits-in-real-life-images-using-cnn-3b48a9ae5e3 
Probably it's something to do with the png that I am reading. 
Here is the exact code that I am using:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from google.colab import drive
# loading the training dataset
drive.mount('/content/drive',force_remount=False)

data = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')

data.head()

Y=data['label']
X=data.drop(['label'],axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train,Y_test  = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size =0.10,stratify=Y)

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X_train, Y_train)

X_test = X_test[:1000]
Y_test=Y_test[:1000]
pred = neigh.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
digits=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
mat = confusion_matrix(Y_test, pred,labels=digits)
print(mat)
sns.heatmap(mat, square=True, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar=False,
            xticklabels=digits, yticklabels=digits)
plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
plt.ylabel('True Label')
plt.show()
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('accuracy = ',accuracy_score(Y_test, pred))

import cv2

image = cv2.imread('2.png')

grey = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(grey.copy(), 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

preprocessed_digits = []
for c in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Creating a rectangle around the digit in the original image (for displaying the digits fetched via contours)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

    # Cropping out the digit from the image corresponding to the current contours in the for loop
    digit = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Resizing that digit to (18, 18)
    resized_digit = cv2.resize(digit, (18,18))
    padded_digit = np.pad(resized_digit, ((5,5),(5,5)), "constant", constant_values=0)
    preprocessed_digits.append(padded_digit)
print("\n\n\n----------------Contoured Image--------------------")
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
inp = np.array(preprocessed_digits)

for digit in preprocessed_digits:
    print(digit.ndim)
    print(digit.shape)
    print(digit.size)
    digit.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    prediction = neigh.predict(digit.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1))
```

Comment: Given the error message, it looks like you're passing in a 4-dimensional object when ```predict()``` requires 2 or fewer. Why does digit have to be 4-dimensional?

Comment: But `digit.ndim` prints 2. which is created from the image = cv2.imread('2.png')
using thresholding. I am not sure why it should be 4 dimensional

Comment: The image.shape = (786, 3136, 3)
  and the grey.shape = (786, 3136) and I am working on the grey image

Comment: Yes, but you print ```digit.ndim``` out before you call ```reshape```. Try calling ```print(digit.ndim)``` after you call ```reshape``` and see if it's still 2 dimensions.

Comment: I got one reason for the error my predict function expects a (1, 28*28) shape. I did digit.reshape(1, 28*28) and it worked